# How do I set up an IIS website that uses a subfolder of a .NET web application as its base?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, iis-6, virtual-directory

I have a .NET web application in which I am developing three separate websites that all share some classes, master pages, etc. (Call the sites `mysite1`, `mysite2`, and `mysite3`)

When I view the site using "View in Browser" from VS (which leads to http://localhost/projectName/mysite1/default.aspx), everything works as expected.

However, I also setup an IIS website called `Mysite1` that uses http://mysite1/ and points to the "mysite1" subfolder as its local path (under Home Directory). When I visit http://mysite1/, I get the following ASP.NET error:

> Parser Error Message: Could not load type
>   'MyProject.Mysite1.Default'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> `Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
>   CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs"
>   Inherits="MyProject.Mysite1.Default" %>`
>
> `Line 2:`
>
> `Line 3:
>   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
>   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

The namespaces are all valid, as evidenced by the site working correctly when run from "View in Browser". I figure it has something to do with the base folder of the application artificially changing because that's what several other errors were caused by, but I don't know how to resolve it.

How should I have configured IIS to use the subfolder of a web application as its base folder?

Comment: Take a look at BlogEngine; it uses this exact set up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Go to the IIS.
> 2. Right Click your WebSite.
> 3. Create the Virtual Directory with the name of mysite1.
> 4. Right click the Virtual Directory mysite1 and select Convert to Application

Now you can operate `http://mysite1/` and pages inside `mysite1`

> **<kbd>CodeBehind</kbd>** = Needs to be compiled ( asp.net 1.1 model) and compiled binary is placed in the bin folder of the website. You
>   need to do a compile in visual studio before you deploy. Good model
>   when you do not want the source code to be viewable as plain text ...
>   for example when delivering to a customer who you not have obligation
>   to provide code.
>
> **<kbd>CodeFile</kbd>** = You provide the source file with the solution for deployment. ASP.NET 2.0 runtime compiles the code when
>   needed. The compiled files are at Microsfot.NET[.NET
>   version]\Temporary ASP.NET Files.

Comment: I didn't have a "Convert to Web Application" option (perhaps because I'm using IIS6?), but I "created" it as an app via the "Application settings" section of the "Virtual Directory" properties. *However*, when I navigate to http://mysite1/, I get the same error and when I go to http://mysite1/mysite1/, I get an authentication failure message (even after setting up authentication settings in IIS for the virtual directory).

Comment: Is it helpful for you http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/1d1c9a73-b4c5-4cfb-ad69-b77fa2e17e19.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: That explains how to convert to an application, which I did. But I still get the same error message.

Comment: I deleted my own answer, so for everyone's future reference, the problem was solved by changing all instances of "CodeBehind=" to "CodeFile=". I do have to include the code files in the MSI's output.